# Configure glassfish to deploy a .war and use jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, derby, war

This is my first question ever in this forum, so I hope you understand my question!

My problem comes when deploying an app in Glassfish.

I've been developing a web application and I have to acces two different databases, a derby database and a mysql database.
While developing from NetBeans IDE 7.4, there has been no problem, I was usign a SessionBean to acces both databases, and configure the connection was too easy. 
I wrote this in the constructor

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
    connectionSoria=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/WEBAPP-Soria","App","App");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  connectionTeruel=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp_teruel","root","root");
```

and everything worked.

The problem came when I built the . war and I tried to deploy it in another computer without NetBeans.
I succeded at deploying it, but when I acces the app, it asks me for the user and password, I write them both, press log in and It doesn't seem to connect with any of the databases.
I searched for, and came to the concusion I had to change the way I connect to databases as I am deploying the app from asadmin in the bin directory of Glassfish.

What I've wrote in the constructor of the bean to connect to the databases is this:

```
ctx1 = new InitialContext();
            ds1 = (DataSource)ctx1.lookup("jdbc/WEBAPP-Soria");
            ds2 = (DataSource)ctx1.lookup("jdbc/WEBAPP_Teruel");

            connectionSoria=ds1.getConnection();
            connectionTeruel=ds2.getConnection();
```

and I added two resources to the glasssfish with

```
C:\glassfishv3\asadmin
asadmin> start-domain
asadmin> deploy E:\AppV2.war
asadmin> add-resources E:\resources.xml
asadmin> restart-domain
```

the content of the resources.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/WEBAPP-Soria" object-type="user" pool-name="WEBAPP-Soria">
<description/>
</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="WEBAPP-Soria" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
<property name="port" value="1527"/>
<property name="databaseName" value="WEBAPP-Soria"/>
<property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/WEBAPP-Soria"/>
<property name="user" value="App"/>
<property name="password" value="App"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/WEBAPP_Teruel" object-type="user" pool-name="WEBAPP_Teruel">
<description/>
</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="WEBAPP_Teruel" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
<property name="port" value="3306"/>
<property name="databaseName" value="WEBAPP_Teruel"/>
<property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WEBAPP_Teruel"/>
<property name="user" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

It doen't work anyway, I am thinking I should add this resources.xml in the directory WEB-INF as glassfish-resources.xml but I don't know if that would work either.

What do you guys suggest I should do?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since your application specifies

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/WEBAPP-Soria
```

as its JDBC Connection URL, it is expecting to connect to an instance of the Derby Network Server on the same machine ("localhost") as your application.

So when you deploy the application, you will also need to deploy the Derby Network Server.

Alternatively, if your intent is to deploy the application on multiple computers, then have them all connect to the same instance of the Derby Network Server, you'll need to specify the hostname or IP address of that single shared instance in place of "localhost" (and ensure that your network allows those connections to be made).